# Yamaha R6 engine stalling when downshifting

Tags: motorcycle, transmission, stall, yamaha

I am using a 2000 Yamaha R6 for this year's track season. Last time I used it I was downshifting from 3rd to 2nd whilst braking at the end of a straight line and the engine stalled locking the wheel (or the wheel locked stalling the engine). This happened two more times after that, at different rpms since I was testing out the behaviour. It was always between 3rd and 2nd. I was blipping the throttle to rev match.

Since then, I tested all the gears up and down by putting the bike on paddock stands. They seemed to work fine and I was unable to reproduce the behaviour.

Now before I open the gearbox blindly searching for something wrong, I'd like to know the possible causes for this behaviour. I'm guessing a damaged shift fork but could it be something else?

Comment: Once it's in gear, is there any issues with it? I mean, can you then use 3rd gear correctly? Or do you never get to use 3rd and have to go to 4th?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 on the paddock stands it runs fine. I tested all gears both ways. Right now I can't try it since it's not road legal.

Comment: I'm wondering if there are some bearing(s) going bad in the tranny which is causing it to lock up under load. I don't know enough about motorcycle transmissions to make any conclusions about it.

Comment: Could it be temperature related - only locking up when thoroughly warm / hot? Can you get it to a track to test it?

Comment: @SolarMike Could be. Throughout the weekend we had more than 30°C so it was definitely not cold. Unfortunately I can't take it to a track until the end of July.